# calling one autohotkey from another

Tags: autohotkey, subroutine

```
^!a: 
run do
run lots
run of
run things
return

^!b: 
run dosomething small
; --- and here I want to do everything that is done for ^!a
```

I can think of two theoretical ways of doing it: 1. By somehow calling the code 2. By generating a ^!a click. I find number 1 better, but how can it be done, if at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a label to a.

```
^!a: 
RunA:
run do
run lots
run of
run things
return

^!b: 
run dosomething small
GoSub, RunA
Return
```